# Play framework 2: Use Array[String] in route

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to generate an url like this:

> /photo?tags=tag1,tag2,tag3

routes file:

```
GET     /photo  controllers.Photos.list(tags:Array[String] ?= "")
```

I got this errors in play console:

> No QueryString binder found for type Array[String]

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: correct way of doing an array in query params(no matter the framework) from what I understand is actually like this /photo?tags=tag1&tags=tag2&tags=tag3 ...it's a bit verbose but the specification allows repetition like that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you should use a common `String` and then take care about converting it to an `Array` in your `controller`

routes:

```
GET     /photo  controllers.Photos.list(tags:String ?= "")
```

in Java:

```
public static Result list (String tags){
    String[] tagsArray = tags.split(",");
    // do something with tagsArray
    return ok();
}
```

Comment: That was my first idea. I will use this solution.

Comment: The way described by @Ahmed Aswani below is the "correct" way to do this in HTTP.

Answer (score 23):

play will bind to array's/lists when the values are in the query 
string or post data with the same name.

this also seems to work:

```
This route: http://localhost/controller/{id}
```

This url: `http://localhost/controller/1?id=2&id=3`

Will bind to `controller(int[] id)` where id -> {1, 2, 3}

posting id=2&id=3 will also bind to an array.

reference:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/c5kB6wmcF8Q

Answer (score 11):

Using a list instead of an array should work.

If you are using Java, it works like this:

```
GET     /photo  controllers.Photos.list(tags: java.util.List[String])
```

Comment: I've searched for this for several hours!

It turns out you cannot just use List[String]. it will use scala type by default!

The following exception will appear!

type mismatch;
 found   : List[String] (in scala.collection.immutable) 
 required: List[_]      (in java.util) 

Use the full package name is the correct way to go

Answer (score 4):

As an aside, if you wish to pass an array of Longs, this works:

`GET     /photo  controllers.Photos.list(tags: java.util.List[java.lang.Long])`

with the controller function taking `List<Long> tags` as an argument.