# Error while accessing List[String] in play framework

Tags: list, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying to access List[String] in controller so I write the code:
My View is

```
@(path:List[String])
   ...
    <button type=submit id=imgButton><a href="@routes.Application.confirmDelete(path)">Delete</a></button>
```

My routes is

```
   GET     /confirmDelete/:path      controllers.Application.confirmDelete(path:List[String])
```

My controller is:

```
def confirmDelete(path:List[String])=Action{
     Ok("deleted "+path);
     }
```

But it gives me error as

```
   No URL path binder found for type List[String]. Try to implement an implicit PathBindable for this type.
```

Answer (score 5):

The error here is absolute clear. Play does not have any idea how to serialize `List[String]` to and from uri. You can implement implicit `PathBindable` conversion for `List[String]` or submit this list as coma separated `String` and build `List[String]` on controllers side from `String` parameter.

Documentation about `PathBindable` - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.PathBindable

Also you may check here for second solution - [Play framework 2: Use Array[String] in route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291136/play-framework-2-use-arraystring-in-route)