# GET form data and bindFromRequest

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, get

I'm writing some test cases for my API and I have a `GET` route entry that looks like;

```
GET /api/nearby  controllers.API.getShopsNearby()
```

And I've defined the appropriate form;

```
case class NearbyForm(lat: String, lon: String)

val nearbyForm = Form(
  mapping("lat" -> nonEmptyText, "lon" -> nonEmptyText)
  (NearbyForm.apply)(NearbyForm.unapply)
)
```

But when I do `nearbyForm.bindFromRequest` I see the form validation always fails since `lat` & `lon` are always empty.

How do we overcome this?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with a `GET` request (and is certainly discouraged), but what happens when you add `parse.urlFormEncoded` as the body parser for your controller `Action`?

Comment: @LimbSoup I did think about that as well, you'd suggest that `lat` & `lon` become part of the URL then?

Comment: Yeah, that would better. Typically GET parameters are query string parameters. e.g. `/location?lat=12.1&lon=45.2`

Comment: Great, thanks, I'm going to stick to that.

Comment: @LimbSoup an unrelated question, but is there a specific way to pass arrays as GET parameters? If I do something like `lat=value1&lat=value2&lat=value3` I see that the bound list just contains `value1`

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291136/play-framework-2-use-arraystring-in-route and pass `lat=value1,value2&lon=value1,value2`